# Changing subject line without splitting up the conversation

Tags: gmail

Is there a way I can change the subject line (example, instead of Re:, I could put In Progress: or Done:) and not have Gmail split the "conversation" into a new email?

Comment: I see that gmail does not even add **RE** for me. are  you trying to do this in an email client like outlook ?

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. From [Change how you see reply emails - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en)

> A conversation breaks off into a new thread if the subject line
>   changes or the conversation reaches more than 100 messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think they fixed this as of now (March 2024). As long as you don't delete a single letter from the original subject, you can add words and (at least for me) the messages are kept in the same conversation in Outlook.